# Encrypting custom ROM

Tags: custom-roms, 5.1-lollipop, encryption, twrp, ota-update

I'd like to encrypt my phone, but I'm afraid it might interfere with the Over-The-Air updates of the custom ROM I installed via flashed TWRP. Does the custom ROM need to support encryption somehow? Is this generally considered seamless or problematic?

Also I am not sure how does the encryption go along with rooted phone. Why do I need to unroot the phone for the encryption process?

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and encrypt your phone. TWRP can decrypt and flash ROMs when given the password. I personally​ use a custom ROM (LineageOS 14.1) and have encryption enabled.

Comment: I did that and the ecryption process was seamless.